# Insertar multiples datos en base de datos en laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, web

Necesito guardar en un array las cadenas de texto que tengo en varios inputs que han sido creado de forma dinamica, para mandarselos al controlador y que este los pueda insertar en la base de datos.

//Esta seria la vista

```
 //ESTO ES EL CODIGO QUE GENERA LOS BOTONES DE AÑADIR Y BORRAR LOS INPUTS DINAMICOS
 <script type="text/javascript">

icremento=0;  

function crear(obj) { 

    icremento++;  
    field = document.getElementById('field');  
    contenedor = document.createElement('div');  
    contenedor.id = 'div'+icremento;  
    field.appendChild(contenedor);  

    boton = document.createElement('input');    
    boton.type = 'text';  
    boton.name = 'text'+icremento;  
    contenedor.appendChild(boton);  

    boton = document.createElement('input');  
    boton.type = 'button';  
    boton.value = 'Borrar';  
    boton.name = 'div'+icremento;  
    boton.onclick = function () {borrar(this.name)}  
    contenedor.appendChild(boton);  
}

function borrar(obj) {  
    field = document.getElementById('field');  
    field.removeChild(document.getElementById(obj));  
}  

</script>  
 <input type="button" value="Crear caja de texto" onclick="crear(this)"  class="btn btn-info"><br><br>
```

//ESTE SERIA EL CONTROLADOR

```
    public function store(Request $request){  
        $date = Carbon::now();  
        $fecha = $date->format('d-m-Y');  
        $localizacion = $request->selector; //recibe informacion de un combobox
    $observaciones = $request->comentarios; //recibe informacion de un 
    textarea

    $tarea = new Tarea();
    $tarea->fecha=$fecha;
    $tarea->zona=$localizacion;
    $tarea->observaciones=$observaciones;

    $tarea->actividades="Y por qui pasaria el array de los datos de los inputs dinamicos";
    $tarea->save();
    return redirect('home');
}
```

Comment: Faltan datos para poder darte una respuesta correcta, por ejemplo que es $tarea->actividades, cuál es la salida html de tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este problema, tienes que colocarle al final del `name` las siguientes llaves `[]` para que todos los inputs que tengan ese nombre **Iguales** se puedan manejar como un [array en PHP](https://cybmeta.com/array-de-inputs-en-formularios-y-procesamiento-con-php).

Inténtalo y nos cuenta que tal te fue.

Comment: Buenas ya lo solucione, efectivamente era poniendo los corchetes al final del name y asi se puede controlar como un array en PHP

En la funcion javascript que me creaba los inputs modifique esto:
boton.name = 'text[]';  
Y en el controlador:
$tareas = $request->input('text');
Al añadir esto recibir todos los datos guardados en el Array

Gracias!